# NVIDIA X Server Settings 'Color range' resets on every reboot and/or log out

Tags: linux, ubuntu, graphics-card, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card

To properly display colors in my `elementary Juno` system (based on `Ubuntu 18.04`) with a `GeForce 9500 GT` card, I need to set the `Color range` to `Limited`, as shown:

[image]

This works, but the problem is that after each reboot, or even if I log out of my session, these settings are lost. I've tried the solution described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/384881/55128) and created a `~/.xinitrc` file that looks like this:

```
nvidia-settings --load-config-only &
. /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

with an `~/.nvidia-settings-rc` file (which I create after setting the colo range to `Limited` in `nvidia-settings`) that looks like this:

```
#
# /home/gabriel/.nvidia-settings-rc
#
# Configuration file for nvidia-settings - the NVIDIA X Server Settings utility
# Generated on Mon Apr  8 16:54:17 2019
#

# ConfigProperties:

RcFileLocale = C
DisplayStatusBar = Yes
SliderTextEntries = Yes
IncludeDisplayNameInConfigFile = Yes
ShowQuitDialog = No
UpdateRulesOnProfileNameChange = Yes
Timer = Memory_Used_(GPU_0),Yes,3000
Timer = Thermal_Monitor_(GPU_0),Yes,1000
Timer = PowerMizer_Monitor_(GPU_0),Yes,1000

# Attributes:

gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/RedBrightness=0.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/GreenBrightness=0.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/BlueBrightness=0.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/RedContrast=0.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/GreenContrast=0.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/BlueContrast=0.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/RedGamma=1.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/GreenGamma=1.000000
gabriel-desk:0[DPY:HDMI-0]/BlueGamma=1.000000
```

Is my system not loading these settings, or is the `Color Range` setting not being saved to the `.nvidia-settings-rc` file? Either way: how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. From what I see, nvidia server settings is persisting thr default configuration instead of the one in memory. So even if it loads it, it's still always the default